# Karate - How to colorfull print

Tags: console, karate

I did a colorful print this way:

```
* print "\x1B[31;40m\n========================================\n\x1B[0m"
```

Is there a simpler way to this approach?

Comment: waste of time in my opinion. ask yourself who this will benefit. what is karate's primary use by your team. anyway, do take a look at the HTML reports (which is what most people would use) which teams typically integrate into CI (Jenkins etc): https://github.com/intuit/karate#test-reports